# Append Pandas dataframe to top of csv file without loading csv file content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

When appending content of dataframe to csv file with "to_csv" the data is appended to the bottom. Is it possible to append the data into the top, without loading all the content of the csv file?

Comment: no... you cannot insert characters into a file generally you would need to  read the file and prepend the new data and write it back out

Answer (score 0):

If your issues is with large file sizes and python memory issues, an easier way is to save the df to_csv and use combining from terminal

in Linux:

```
sed 1d file_*.csv > merge.csv
```

in winodws:

```
copy file*.csv > merge.csv
```